# Filtering dropdown menus using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason, some of the selections work but most don't. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, maybe you can help?
Here is a live demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/dHmge
My jQuery:

```
$('#ddlOffice option').hide();
    $('#ddlBusiness').change(function(){
      var selectedBusiness = $( "#ddlBusiness option:selected").val();
      selectedBusiness = parseFloat(selectedBusiness);
      $('#ddlOffice option').hide();
      $('#ddlOffice option[value="'+selectedBusiness+'"]').show();
      $('#txtBusiness').val($( "#ddlBusiness option:selected").text());
    });

     $('#ddlOffice').change(function(){
      $('#txtOffice').val($( "#ddlOffice option:selected").text());
    });
```

Bonus points:   I would like to do this without jQuery, if anyone has tips on an easy way of doing the showing and hiding in raw javascript or wants to do a fork without jQuery would be awesome,

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you want to do? I think you want users to use one select box to select number of businesses and then change options of another select box based on that. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now I would just like to convert it to raw javascript and not depend on jQuery for this since its the only javascript the app uses.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a better way:

```
var options = $("#ddlOffice").html();
$("#ddlBusiness").change(function(e) {
    var selectedValue = $("#ddlBusiness :selected").val();
    $("#ddlOffice").html(options);
    $('#ddlOffice :not([value="'+selectedValue+'"])').remove();
});
```

Now Working CodePen: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/dHmge

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote your jQuery code and now it seems to be working for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faridv/Mf5g8/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('#ddlOffice option').hide();
    $('#ddlBusiness').change(function(){
        var selectedBusiness = parseFloat($("#ddlBusiness").val());
        $('#ddlOffice option').hide();
        $('#ddlOffice option[value="' + selectedBusiness + '"]').show();
        $('#txtBusiness').val($("#ddlBusiness option:selected").text());
    });
    $('#ddlOffice').change(function(){
        $('#txtOffice').val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

Please consider:

1. If you are putting your JavaScript before your HTML, remember to use `document.ready` or `$(function(){ })` in jQuery.
2. You can't have options with same values as you did in `#ddlOffice` select. I mean what's the purpose of using options that will return same values?!
3. You haven't closed one of your `option`s in second `select`.