# Dynamic cascading button list in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to figure out a way to have cascading button filters in ASP.NET

For example:

Department : Math, Science, History
If click Math.. buttons for line appear.. Line: 1 , 2, 3  if click Science...Line: 4 , 5, 6

And then if I click a Line, a list of team buttons appear.. Team: A B C

Each button would be filtering a grid. Also the buttons text must be populated from a database table. So the amount of buttons will be dynamic based on what is populated in the table.

What would be the best approach to something like this? Would it be better to do a cascading drop down list using the ajax toolkit? Or is there a way to do it with buttons, for example with a Repeater control?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery's AJAX functions, personally. You could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', "select#department", function(){
  $.getJSON("/Service/GetLinesById",
    {id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'},
    function(data){
    var options = '';        
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + data[i].title + '">' + data[i].title + '</option>';
    }    
    $('select#lines').html(options);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ajax and jQuery you find a ton of gorgeous menus which you can see how they work and try to mimic them.

Comment: Do you have any examples of that type of menu filtering?

Comment: @zbrady http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198326/filtering-dropdown-menus-using-jquery      http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/14/ui-elements-search-box/